# how to get matlab to open current folder in finder?

Tags: matlab, path, directory

how to get matlab to open current folder in finder?  I find this useful on network computers.
Also how to get the path of something in the setpath folder   I see something like  \software ...  and I would like to get the complete beginning of the path

Comment: Please elaborate.  What do you mean by "current folder in finder"?

Comment: you mean something like `! open .` does?

Comment: What is the "setpath folder"? Please edit your question to provide an example.

Comment: I mean what opens up when you are in home and click the setpath button under preferences its the paths that matlab has, however I can only see the end of my path /software/cplex..   and I need to know the beginning to find the folder.

Answer (score 4):

To open a new OS X Finder window from Matlab you'll need to execute a Terminal command using [`unix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unix.html) or [`system`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html), e.g.:

```
unix('open ~/Desktop')
```

will open the current user's Desktop folder. To open Matlab's current directory (see `pwd`), use the [dot command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_(command)):

```
unix('open .') % Equivalent to: unix(['open ' pwd])
```

The [`!` operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html) can be used as well as shorthand for `system`.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to also answer the question of "how to open the current directory in finder"

Comment: @excaza: Good point. I was assuming too much familiarity with UNIX.

Comment: anything you can do with the graphical version of matlab?

Comment: @HaoSun: Well, you can also type Command-O to open a file browser (that I think launches with the current folder visible). The same thing can be accomplished by clicking the "Home" tab in Matlab, then clicking on the folder icon for "Open".